# Why do some user profile photos display a larger thumbnail and description and others don't?

Tags: support, profile-picture, tooltips, user-card

Sometimes the profile picture thumbnail that appears below an answer is converted into a larger picture and description, sort of a tooltip, upon mouseover, while other pictures don't display that behavior.

Below I just took a random profile to show the described behaviour.

Before mouseover:

[image]

During mouseover:

[image]

1. Is that intentional?
2. If yes, what are the criteria used to differentiate whether to display the enlarged version or not?

Comment: Two words: [expanded usercard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user). Searching for the dupe...